# Pytorch dataset download triggers IDM

Tags: pytorch

I normally use Internet Download Manager to download my files, but I don't want Pytorch triggering IDM everything I try to download datasets. For example:

```
training_data = datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root="data",
    train=True,
    download=True,
    transform=ToTensor()
)
```

Triggers IDM like this:
[image]

Is there anyway for me to make IDM not do this? Is this IDM's fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the progress bar to the PyTorch's built-in download progress bar by:

```
import os
os.environ['TORCH_HOME'] = './data'
```